# Is there anyway to populate an outlook email from an asp.net-mvc web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, outlook

I want to have a webpage where if you click on it, it opens up (but doesn't send) an email from outlook.  Is this possible?  I want to programatically populate the subject and the To, CC and the body.

Comment: Will all of your visitors have Outlook and Internet Explorer installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple! Just customize [mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto#Example) link

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

After pressing the link above, user will get default mail client opened, with filled in to, cc, subject and body.

Comment: This would work with whatever your default email client is.  If you can rely on that being Outlook (assuming you require Outlook at all), this would be the way to go.

Comment: You beat me to it. Good answer.

Comment: I wouldn't want outlook to open, GMail!